intersection of kernels for bilinear forms
I have
$$
b_{\Omega_i} (u,v) = a_{\Omega_i} (u,v) - k^2(u,v)_{\Omega_i} 
$$
and
$$
(\Xi(u), \Xi(v)_ {1, k, \Omega_i} = a_{\Omega_i} (u,v) + k^2(u,v)_{\Omega_i}.
$$
Where
$$
a_{\Omega_i}(u,v)= \int_{\Omega_i} A\nabla u \cdot \nabla v  
$$
and
$$
(u, v)_ {\Omega_i} = \int_{\Omega_i} uv.  
$$
I'm using a finite element space, $V_i$ that is non-zero on the boundary. $\Omega_i$ is a subdomain of $\Omega$  and $k^2 > 0$. $\Xi$ is the partition of unity operator the will send the functions to zero on the boundary of $\Omega_i$. I'm trying find the intersect of $ker (b_{\Omega_i} (u,v))$ and $ker ((\Xi(u), \Xi(v)_ {1, k, \Omega_i})$. I can see that $ker ((\Xi(u), \Xi(v)_ {1, k, \Omega_i})$ would be the set of functions that are non-zero on the boundary, but zero on the internal nodes of $\Omega_i$, and from the definition of $b_{\Omega_i} (u,v)$, I can see that $ker (b_{\Omega_i} (u,v))$ will be $u \in V_i$ s.t
$$
a(u,v) = k^2 (u, v) \quad \forall v \in V_i.
$$
But I am sturgling to find what $ker (b_{\Omega_i} (u,v)) \cap ker ((\Xi(u), \Xi(v)_ {1, k, \Omega_i})$ would be. I am hoping that
$$
ker (b_{\Omega_i} (u,v)) \cap ker ((\Xi(u), \Xi(v)_ {1, k, \Omega_i}) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace
$$
but i'm not sure this is the case, or even where to begin trying to show this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
